# Weighted Grade book Project

Tags: python, python-3.x

Create a program that will calculate a student’s grade in a class that uses a weighted gradebook.

A weighted system uses percentages to determine how much each assignment category is worth. For this project, use the following percentages:

- Project Grades = 30% (weight = .30)
- Participation Grades = 20% (weight = .20)
- Quizzes = 10% (weight = .10)
- Exams = 40% (weight = .40)

Grading scale:

- A - 90-100
- B - 80-89
- C - 70-79
- D - 60-69
- F - Below 60

Note: You will multiply the average for each of the categories by its weight. The final grade is the sum of the calculated weights.

Can't get the code to the allow the user to enter grades in all 4 categories, because it gets stuck on the first category chosen and the loop just goes on and on without stopping asking for a list of scores. I attempted a loop inside a loop, but it only continued on the first one chosen as well. Need multiple grades entered into all 4 categories which is why I need the program to allow the user to enter grades to the other categories not just the one that is chosen first.

```
print ("Weighted Grade Calculator ")
name = input("Enter the Student's Name ")
number = input("Enter the Student's Number ")

x = input("Enter Assignment type: ")
c = 'y'

#Loop is in case user wants to calculate another students grade
while c=='y' or c=='Y':
  if x >= "quiz" or x >= "Quiz":
    input_string = input("Enter a list of scores separated by space ")
#Read ints separated by spaces
    lst = input_string.split()
    print("Calculating sum of element of input list")
#convert strings to ints and convert map to list
    lst = list(map(int, lst))
#Find total and avg
    total = sum(lst)
    avg_1 = total/len(lst)

  elif x >= "project" or x >= "Project":
    input_string = input("Enter a list of scores separated by space ")
    lst = input_string.split()
    print("Calculating sum of element of input list")
    lst = list(map(int, lst))
    total = sum(lst)
    avg_2 = total/len(lst)

  elif x >= "participation" or x >= "Participation":
    input_string = input("Enter a list of scores separated by space ")
    lst = input_string.split()
    lst = list(map(int, lst))
    total = sum(lst)
    avg_3 = total/len(lst)

  elif x >= "exam" or x >= "Exam":
    input_string = input("Enter a list of scores separated by space ")
    lst = input_string.split()
    print("Calculating sum of element of input list")
    lst = list(map(int, lst))
    total = sum(lst)
    avg_4 = total/len(lst)

  else:
    print("error, please try again")


    #Finds percentage earned from each category
    w_quiz = avg_1 * 0.1
    w_project = avg_2 * 0.3
    w_participation = avg_3 * 0.2
    w_exams = avg_4 * 0.4

    total = w_project + w_quiz + w_participation + w_exams 
    if(total >= 90 and total <=100):
        grade = 'A'
    elif(total >= 80 and total < 90):
        grade = 'B'
    elif(total >= 70 and total < 80):
        grade = 'C'
    elif(total >= 60 and total < 70):
        grade = 'D'
    elif(total >= 0 and total < 60):
        grade = 'F'
    print ("Student Name: " + str(name))
    print ("Student ID: " + str(number))
    print ("Total Weighted Score: " + str(total) + "%")
    print ("Letter Grade: " + grade)
    c = input("Would you like to calculate another grade? (Y or N): ")
```

Comment: What do you mean by no luck? Can you give an example of input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: @foobarbaz Basically i need to enter multiple grade in to each category (Quizzes, Exam, Participation, and Project). Lets say I enter quiz for the first input then the grade goes to a list that only has other quiz grades entered then the program ask if I want to enter another grade in and I say 'yes' but this time I enter Exam for the category, the grade that is entered should go in a different list made up only of exam grades.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but this code will take as much input as you give it and at the end will calculate the average of all totals and its respective letter grade:

```
def calculate_letter(total):
    #function calculates letter grade
    if(total >= 90 and total <=100):
        grade = 'A'
    elif(total >= 80 and total < 90):
        grade = 'B'
    elif(total >= 70 and total < 80):
        grade = 'C'
    elif(total >= 60 and total < 70):
        grade = 'D'
    elif(total >= 0 and total < 60):
        grade = 'F'
    return grade

print ("Weighted Grade Calculator ")
name = input("Enter the Student's Name ")
number = input("Enter the Student's Number ")

totals = [] #initialize list to append scores to

while True:
    project = float(input("Enter the percentage for Projects (numbers only): "))
    participation = float(input("Enter the percentage for the Participation (numbers only): "))
    quizzes = float(input("Enter the percentage for Quizzes (numbers only): "))
    exams = float(input("Enter the percentage for the Final Exam (numbers only): "))

    w_project = project * 0.3
    w_participation = participation * 0.2
    w_quiz = quizzes * 0.1
    w_exams = exams * 0.4

    total = w_project + w_quiz + w_participation + w_exams

    grade = calculate_letter(total) #running the function defined above to evaluate letter grade from total
    print ("Total Weighted Score: " + str(total) + "%")
    print ("Letter Grade: " + grade)
    c = input("Would you like to calculate another grade? (Y or N): ").lower()

    totals.append(total)
    if c == 'y':
        #restarts the loop
        continue
    else:
        #exits the loop
        break

print(totals)
final_averaged_score = sum(totals) / len(totals) #finding the average of the list
final_grade = calculate_letter(final_averaged_score)
print ("Student Name: " + str(name))
print ("Student ID: " + str(number))
print ("Final Averaged score: " + str(final_averaged_score))
print ("Final letter grade: " + str(final_grade))
```